# Convert a ontology to a graph

Tags: graph, ontology

How to convert an ontology (.owl or .rdf) in a graph or an adjacency matrix?
Is there any tool?

Comment: That really depends where you want to store your graph.  In memory? in a graph database? in an existing triple store? ...  If you have a library to read N3/RDF it's fairly easy to store it in a graph but harder to reason over it once you have it there.

Comment: @user941273 Where you able to find any such tools?

Answer (score 2):

it is possibile to extract nodes and edges by using OWL API (Java API) available [here](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/). morever, you can use GraphX spark's API that takes nodes and edges to produce a property graph (directed multigraph) as explained [at this link](https://jcrisch.wordpress.com/2015/09/05/charger-une-ontologie-owl-dans-spark-graphx/).

Answer (score 1):

It largely depends what you want to do. For example, [RFD - Gravity](http://semweb.salzburgresearch.at/apps/rdf-gravity/), by Salzburg Research, provides a nice visualisation for both OWL and RDF files; and [Protégé](http://protege.stanford.edu/), by Stanford University, is a very popular Ontology editor. Both of them are written in Java and free of charge, and Protégé is open source.

You can fnid more Semantic Web tools in this URL: http://www.w3.org/wiki/SemanticWebTools.

Comment: What do you mean by "It largely depends what you want to do"? The OP's question is very clear: "to convert an ontology (.owl or .rdf) to a graph or an adjacency matrix". An adjacency matrix is an adjacency matrix, nothing to do with "visualisation" or "editing".